# Fastest way to iterate an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I'm studying for the [Zend PHP certification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_(company)#Zend_Certification_Test).

I am not sure about the answer to this question.

> **Question:  What is the best way to iterate and modify every element of an array using PHP 5?**
>
> a) You cannot modify an array during iteration
>
> b) `for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { /* ... */ }`
>
> c) `foreach($array as $key => &$val) { /* ... */ }`
>
> d) `foreach($array as $key => $val) { /* ... */ }`
>
> e) `while(list($key, $val) = each($array)) { /* ... */  }`

---

My instinctive is (B) since there is no need to create a temporary variable, but then I realize it won't work for associative arrays.

Further searching around the Internet I found this:

Storing the invariant array count in a separate variable improves performance.

```
$cnt = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) { }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From these options, C would be the obvious answer.

The remaining options (besides A) *may* be used to achieve that, depending on the code inside the parenthesis, but the question does *not* show that code. So it must be C.

And you are answering the wrong question - yes, doing count() before the *for* cycle will improve performance, but this question is not about performance.

Comment: The "using PHP `5`" part may also be a hint. b),d),e) are possible in php4 but c) isn't. Granted, that's weak evidence but exam question often work that way ;-) Since you need another table lookup to access the element for b,d,e it seems obvious that c) is "the best" way (given the choices). The manual also states that this doesn't work with `foreach(array(1,2,3) as &$v)`, the traversable must be a variable.

Answer (score 10):

You can iterate and modify every element of an array with any of the shown constructs. But some notes on that:

b) Is only useful if the array is a numeric array with the keys from 0 to n-1.

c) Is useful for both kinds of arrays. Additionally `$value` is a reference of the element’s value. So changing `$value` inside [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) will also change the original value.

d) Like c) except `$value` is a copy of the value (note that `foreach` operates on a copy of `$array`). But with the key of the element you can access and change the original value with `$array[$key]`.

e) Like d). Use `$array[$key]` to access and change the original element.

Answer (score 2):

[SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) would be the best answer here.

Comment: SPL doesn't solve the question. Even if it was available as an answer, we're talking looping, not the Traversable being looped.

Comment: SPL is "Standard PHP Library". Can you elaborate in your answer? How does this answer the question?

Comment: I agree with Peter.  Link-only hints that make no attempt to demonstrate implementation are all-too-common in Stack Overflow's "early years".  I feel they all should be transferred to a comment under the question.