# The best way to increase every item of php array by the same value

Tags: php, arrays, string, reference, foreach

What's the best way to increase every item of php numeric array by the same value?

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596988/fastest-way-to-iterate-array-in-php) in SO
one of the best answers for this question is:

```
foreach($array as $key => &$val) { 
  $val+=5;//   typo   $val[$key]+=5; was just fixed.
}
```

Correct?

Is there any better/shorter/faster way to do that?

Comment: 3 lines of code that is executed fast. Why would you do it another way... This is easy and highly readable.

Comment: If you don't use `$key` - don't specify it in `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the <strike>shorter</strike> oneliner:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$i) { $i += 5; });
```

And it's not the code you need to optimize and find for the fastest, so choose the more readable one for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your code <strike>is</strike> was actually wrong; it won't work, but this will:

```
foreach ($array as &$val) { 
  $val += 5;
}
```

This is probably the fastest as well, one simple `foreach` and no function calls.