# Three-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

How can I iterate over this array? Syntax of loop

```
$t = array(
  'grn_id' => array(
    'status_id' => array(1, 2, 3, 4)
  )
)
```

Comment: What output are you expecting from this? And also show us the full array.

Comment: nested `foreach` loops?

Comment: ouptut = 1 2 3 4

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to iterate array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596988/fastest-way-to-iterate-array-in-php)

Comment: Are you only wanting the "leaf nodes" (non-array-type values) from the multidimensional array?  How about an array function that can walk recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words, if you want that, you can get:

```
foreach ($t["grn_id"]["status_id"] as $statusId)
  echo $statusId;
```

You will get `1, 2, 3, 4` in each iteration.

```
foreach ($t["grn_id"] as $grn) {
  foreach ($grn as $statusId) {
    echo $statusId;
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a possibilty if i can access or output all 'status_id' keys (if i put many keys like 'status_id'), can output them?

Comment: You mean you have one 'status_id' and one 'status_id2'?

Comment: @AyushKumar That's what my code does... What next? I don't understand.

Comment: @Praveen your code outputs 1 2 3 4, but if i want to print 'status_id'...

Comment: He means the second layer is multiple. Your foreach is only printing "status_id" not all possible parts of "grn_id"

Comment: @Praveen didn't want to mess with your answer since it's hard to type on phone sometimes. But I think this is what he is looking for: `foreach ($t["grn_id"] as $grn){
        foreach ($grn as $statusId){
          echo $statusId;
        }
    }` sorry bout that. Now the edits are done :-)

Comment: @Andreas Can i do this  `echo $grn` in first foreach loop

Comment: @Andreas I'll try to use the code from your comment and update my answer.

Comment: Echo $grn won't work as $grn is an array. @Praveen :thumbs up:

Comment: @Andreas This question and answer is screwed up... Let's move on bro. Totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [recursive iterator](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) is what you're looking for ?

You can check the example given :

```
<?php 
$myArray = array( 
    0 => 'a', 
    1 => array('subA','subB',array(0 => 'subsubA', 1 => 'subsubB', 2 => array(0 => 'deepA', 1 => 'deepB'))), 
    2 => 'b', 
    3 => array('subA','subB','subC'), 
    4 => 'c' 
); 

$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($myArray); 
iterator_apply($iterator, 'traverseStructure', array($iterator)); 

function traverseStructure($iterator) { 

    while ( $iterator -> valid() ) { 

        if ( $iterator -> hasChildren() ) { 

            traverseStructure($iterator -> getChildren()); 

        } 
        else { 
            echo $iterator -> key() . ' : ' . $iterator -> current() .PHP_EOL;    
        } 

        $iterator -> next(); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

And the output is :

```
0 : a 
0 : subA 
1 : subB 
0 : subsubA 
1 : subsubB 
0 : deepA 
1 : deepB 
2 : b 
0 : subA 
1 : subB 
2 : subC 
4 : c
```

Comment: Link only answer are usually not liked. Copy the part you want to link to here instead.